# Enable pod for exact build configuration

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, podfile, buildconfiguration

I am looking for the ability to install and use pod for only one exact build configuration in my project.
I assume that something needs to be done in Podfile.
Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Use this format

```
# Podfile

platform :ios, '12.0'
    
# Available pods for all targets
def available_pods
    pod 'AFNetworking'
    pod 'Reachability'
end

target 'targetName1' do
  available_pods
end

target 'targetName2' do
    available_pods
    pod 'YourTargetSpecificPod'
end
```

Comment: thanks
I king of used another technic that worked for me 
:configurations => 'Mybuildconfigl'